# Scanning webpage finding values using Regex but ignore form fields

Tags: jquery

I have a function which scans a webpage to find values using a regular expression.

It's working really well, but it's finding the values inside text areas and text inputs and I want to ignore those.

The `processDocument()` is the function run on page load.

```
const regex = /\s*(([+]?(\s?\d)([-\s]?\d)|0)?(\s?\d)([-\s]?\d){9}|[(](\s?\d)([-\s]?\d)+\s*[)]([-\s]?\d)+)\s*/;

function handleTextNode(textNode) {
    if(textNode.parentElement) {
        textNode.parentElement.innerHTML = textNode.parentElement.innerHTML.replace(regex, function(match){
            return `<i class="fa fa-phone-square" style="color:#e52420;"></i> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="c2d_phonenumber" style="background:#e52420; color:#ffffff">${match}</a>`;
        });
    }
}

function textNodesUnder(el) {
    var n, a=[], walk=document.createTreeWalker(el,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false);
    while(n=walk.nextNode()) a.push(n);
    return a;
}

function processDocument() {
    let nodeList = textNodesUnder(document.body);
    nodeList = nodeList.filter(node => regex.test(node.nodeValue)).filter(textNode => textNode.nodeName === "#text" && textNode.parentNode.nodeName !== "SCRIPT" && textNode.parentNode.nodeName !== "STYLE");
    
    nodeList.forEach(function (el) {
        handleTextNode(el);
    });
}
```

Comment: Your code does not show when or how they are used. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Twisty sorry, it's the `processDocument` that is run on page load

Comment: Since you did not provide an example, there is no way to know what DOM elements are being read. Therefore, can't figure out why it's reading more than it should.